# Jquery blur function: Run second function after first. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to get a second function to run based on the results of the first.

```
$('#email').blur(function () {

id = $(this).attr('id');
$(myObj).data(id,""); 

is_email(id); // If it's a valid email, it does this: $(myObj).data(id,"ok");

// Now if it's a valid email address, I want to run a second function to see if
// it's already taken.

if ($(myObj).data("email") == "ok") {

    $(myObj).data("email",""); // Resets the value...
    is_taken(id, "employees", "email"); // To test it again...

}   

});
```

The first part works fine, but when I get to if($(myObj).... it is never checked. I'm assuming because this is set on the same blur event. I thought by putting it AFTER the first function, it would check the value of this object after the first function was complete. My guess is that it's checking if the value is "ok" before the first function has had a chance to return the value.

Comment: Please state what you are trying to achieve as well, "I'm trying to validate an email address" for instance, give us some background. Also, your code looks fine to me. Please prepare a http://jsfiddle.net example that shows your problem

Comment: Does `is_email` send an ajax request? Could you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Yes, is_email and is_taken both send an ajax request. I tried just putting an alert box after 'if email is ok', but even that won't display.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify it and get it all together... here is the javascript part: http://jsfiddle.net/rfErS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the functions use AJAX, the second is being invoked before the first AJAX call returns and sets the data value. The key letter in AJAX is the first 'A' - asynchronous, meaning the code flow continues without waiting for the response. You can avoid this (and avoid using `data` to store the intermediate results) by changing your `is_email` function to accept a callback. Run the second function as the callback when the AJAX call completes depending on the result of the first call.

```
function is_email( id, type, check, callback )
{
     var that = this;
     $.post( '/email/check', $('#'+id).val(), function(result) {
           if (result == 'ok') {
                if (callback) {
                   callback.call(that,id,type,check);
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Used as:

```
is_email(id, "employees", "email", istaken);
```

Comment: I'm sure my solution lies in this, however these different functions use different parameters. That's why I was trying to get it back to the original blur function so that I can specify the different parameters for the second function... How could this be done with a callback?

Comment: @user971230 I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but you could set the parameter values on the element that the `blur` handler is applied to and extract them from it using `data`.   `<input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-type="employees" data-check="email" />` ... `$('#email').blur( function() { var $this = $(this), type = $(this).data('type'), check = $(this).data('check'); ...`